# Django query for many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following two models

```
class Questionnaire(models.model)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
     type = models.CharField(max_length=128,choices=questionnaire_choices) 

class TestPopulation(models.Model)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
      age = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
      education = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, 
                                   choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)
     questionnaire = models.ManyToManyField(Questionnaire, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now how can i get number of questionnaires for the specific user (logged in user). ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
test_population = TestPopulation.objects.get(user=user)
test_population.questionnaire.all()
```

Comment: He need the number so: `test_population.questionnaire.count()`

Comment: This is wrong. User is a foreign key, that means a user can have multiple test_population. That will result in exception if you do a get. Instead do filter and for each TestPopulation get the count and sum up the individual count. Clear way would be to annotate the TestPopulation query with count.

Answer (score 4):

```
questionnaire.objects.filter(test_population__user=user).count()
```